# Find and replace characters in strings in all .xlsx files in folder VBA

Tags: vba, loops, replace

I am trying to replace characters such as "/" and "ó", and also a line break (alt + ENTER, manually replaced in excel with find and replace with CTRL + J) in excel files (.xlsx). The characters can be found all over the excel sheets (not one particular range). The reason that I would like to replace these values is that these characters are giving me errors in another application.
I have 20 excel files in one folder, with multiple sheets. I would like to make a script (vba macro) to loop through the excel files and all its sheets and do the replacements.
I am very new with vba/macros.

```
    Sub ReplaceStringInFile()

    Dim sBuf As String
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim sFileName As String
    Dim FileExt(2) As String


    ChDir = "C:\mydirectory\"

    FileExt(1) = "xlsx"

    For i = 1 To 1

      sFileName = Dir("*." & FileExt(i))

      Do

        If sFileName = "" Then Exit Do

        sTemp = ""
        Open sFileName For Input As #1
          Do Until EOF(1)
            Line Input #1, sBuf
            sTemp = sTemp & sBuf & vbCrLf
          Loop
        Close #1

        sTemp = Replace(sTemp, "ó", "o")
        sTemp = Replace(sTemp, "/", "")

        Open sFileName For Output As #1
           Print #1, sTemp
        Close #1

        sFileName = Dir()

  Loop

Next i

End Sub
```

I have tried to combine code from scripts mentioned here:
[Find and replace string in all excel files in folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14840574/find-and-replace-string-in-all-excel-files-in-folder;) and here
[Excel macro to find and replace multiple strings in any text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37291553/excel-macro-to-find-and-replace-multiple-strings-in-any-text-file;)
[Loop through files in a folder using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380312/loop-through-files-in-a-folder-using-vba)

But I didn't get it to work.

Help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Can you edit your post with the code you currently have?

Comment: Yes sorry, I am struggling to get the code copied in nicely with all the indents etc. Sorry

Comment: I recommend you break your problem into smaller pieces.  Step 1) Can you  read all Excel file names in a directory?  2) Can you open up an Excel file?  3) Do you know how to loop through all sheets 4) For a single sheet, can you find/replace?  Try try tackle one step at a time. BTW, your code assumes text files.  If you are opening up Excel files, you are on a completely wrong path using "Line Input"

Comment: Hi Ernie, thank you. I can only do step 4. Ah.. I do not have .text files. What would I need for excel files?